# How do I fail check a valid API?

Tags: java, api

I am using processing:

loadStrings("http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=" + sym);

The problem is that I want to be able to catch if sym is invalid instead of display a fake stock. Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how the API works that you are using, but just quickly testing in a browser:

The request for http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=AADF (e.g. A bad stock)

will respond with "httpserver.cc: Response Code 400"

Can you just check for that response (A 400 Code)?

Comment: It gives an IO exception instead of returning that "httpserver.cc: Response Code 400" string. I've tried try/catch blocks with a general Exception and it doesn't work either. I've also tried checking the variable I load it into as null.

Comment: `try {
  response = loadStrings("http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=" + sym);
  } catch(Exception e){
    stockName = "This stock does not exist";
  }`

Comment: but I found out loadStrings returns null so I messed up when checking it in my earlier tests